# Como inserir um div dentro de um div específica usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Este é meu código, quero inserir ele dentro de uma div com a id específica.
Mais no momento estou com dificuldade de fazer ele aparecer na div que eu quero.

```
var html =
  '<div class="card">' +
      '<div class="poster"><img id="id00" src=""></div>' +
      '<div class="details">' +
        '<h6>Post name<br><span><a class="link" href="#" target="_blank"></a></span></h6>' +
        '<div class="description"><small><b>Descrição</b></small>' +
          '<ul class="list-unstyled scroll lead">' +
            '<li id="description"></li>' +
          '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<button id="id01" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-light">Baixar</button>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que pegar a div depois adicionar nela a que criou com um [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), assim também, como pode utilizar [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) para não ter que ficar utilizando concatenação **`+`**:

```js
let html =
  `<div class="card">
      <div class="poster"><img id="id00" src=""></div>
      <div class="details">
        <h6>Post name<br><span><a class="link" href="#" target="_blank"></a></span></h6>
        <div class="description"><small><b>Descrição</b></small>
          <ul class="list-unstyled scroll lead">
            <li id="description"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="id01" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-light">Baixar</button>
      </div>
    </div>`;

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById('especifica').appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="especifica"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Até o momento tudo está correto (se o seu objetivo é criar um novo elemento). Depois de ter inserido o conteúdo no elemento, basta utilizar o método `appendChild` para adicionar o elemento criado a um outro elemento, dessa forma:

```js
const content = "Hello World";
const main = document.getElementById("main");

let element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = content;
main.appendChild(element);
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Caso o seu objetivo seja adicionar somente os elementos da string sem precisar criar um novo elemento, você pode apenas obter o elemento principal e atribuir o conteúdo a ele.

```js
const content = "<div>Hello World<div>";
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```